# How to obtain value of Notes count column

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I have created a view that lists a count of the documents for contracts with certain Contractor ID's.  One column is a count column, not categorized and hard coded with the formula of "1" and set to be a Total.  Second column is ContractorID set to the field ContractorID and is Categorised.  This is good so far but I wish to output the documents that have the same ContractorID.  I have tried amending the View using a count on the "Count" column but without success.  I also tried sorting the "Count" column in descending order to show at the top the documents where the same ContractorID is used but this doesn't appear to work either.  Lastly, I tried using an agent to determine the value of the "Count" column but this only seemed to recognize the value of "1". How can I get the agent to determine if the value is not "1" or further filter the view to only show ones with count greater than "1"?

Here is an extract of the agent code;

```
Dim columnCount As Integer

Set requestDoc1 = viewContractors.GetFirstDocument
Do Until requestDoc1  Is Nothing
columnCount = requestDoc1.Columnvalues(0)
strContratorID = requestDoc1.getitemvalue("ContractorID")
    If columnCount <> 1 Then
    ..... Add strContratorID to list to output
    End if
Set requestDoc1 = viewContractors.Getnextdocument(requestDoc1)
Loop
```

Here is a screen dump of the view I wish to either further filter or the agent to manipulate

[image: Contractor View Sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use NotesViewNavigator and NotesViewEntry- objects.

NotesDocument always represent a DOCUMENT in the view (the single line), but never the category itself. That's why you need NotesViewentries: they can also represent category- lines.

To get a list will all documents that are "duplicate" you could do something like this:

```
Dim viwNav As NotesViewNavigator
Dim veCat As NotesViewEntry

Set viwNav = viewContractors.Createviewnav()
Set veCat = viwNav.Getfirst()

While Not veCat Is Nothing
    If veCat.Columnvalues(0) > 0 Then
        strContratorID = veCat.Columnvalues(1)
        '- ..... Add strContratorID to list to output
    End If
    Set veCat = viwNav.Getnextcategory( veCat )
Wend
```

Unfortunately totals- columns cannot be sorted by their total value nor filtered. So you really NEED to go the "code"- way.

Answer (score 0):

1) In my opinion you should change the position of the two columns:

[image]

2) Here's the adapted code of your agent:

```
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim viewContractors As NotesView
    Dim viewNavigator As NotesViewNavigator
    Dim viewEntry As NotesViewEntry

    Dim contractorID As String
    Dim columnCount As Integer

    Set db = session.CurrentDataBase
    Set viewContractors = db.getView("Contractors")

    Set viewNavigator = viewContractors.CreateViewNav()

    Set viewEntry = viewNavigator.Getfirst()
    While Not(viewEntry Is Nothing)
        If viewEntry.Iscategory Then
            contractorID = viewEntry.Columnvalues(0)
            columnCount = viewEntry.Columnvalues(1)
        End If
        Set viewEntry = viewNavigator.Getnextcategory(viewEntry)
    Wend
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try changing the columns round.  You responded after I had implemented Torstens suggestion above

Comment: Changing the order of the columns is not needed to fix the problem... I always keep the total before the category: In this case all strings are the same length, but when the category can be different lengths, then it can be cut by the total column...

Comment: @TorstenLink: Yes, you are right, it's an interesting point of view.